# how can I access programatillcay to the subview which I've created it using Interface builder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to know how can I invoke(access) a subView that I've created it using IB
I've used this code but no chance :

```
mySubView * mysbv = [mySubView alloc];
[mysbv setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

but yet I will get compile error says undeclared mySubView where as I have create mySubView class and its attached to the window inside IB.

and by the way is it good practice to use components using IB or do I have to create them programmatically (although I have problem to it either)?

Comment: People who down mark should really explain why.

Comment: +1. In this instance I'd say its probably the English. But not everyone's first language is English so it doesn't deserve a downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using nib files is far more powerful; in general, code examples that create UI elements are from the prehistoric days before Apple supported IB for iPhoneOS.

Your code example really won't work - you can't ever just use `alloc` on its own.  Create an IBOutlet property for your view controller, and connect it to your view; it will be available for use from `awakeFromNib`/`viewDidLoad` onwards.

Comment: I strongly disagree with your first sentence. Personally I only find nibs useful for very simple apps. In my opinion the right approach to use is defined by what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: -1 for the fist statement. In no way nib files are more flexible than programming by hand. Good for quick jobs, but so limited for a professional work.

Comment: Creating code programmatically is slow and prone to errors.  There are cases to do this, certainly, but only when the nib option isn't feasible.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to declare a view and then access it in Interface Builder, declare the UIView as an IBOutlet in your class.
Once you add any view in IB, control click from your file's owner to the view you want to associate with it.

Also, if the UIView is your custom class (in this case mySubView), make sure the class of the UIView is changed to mySubView. This can be found in your Identity Inspector in IB.